# Creature fights target creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I've read a few cards that say this and only just now notices while reading [Hunt the Weak](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hunt%20the%20Weak)

It says specifically "Each deals damage equal to its power to the other"

So does a +1/+1 counter add to its power?
Basically my question is do you use the power printed on the card, or the power that creature has in normal combat?
And does trample have any effect to the player whose creature Im targeting if their creature can't take all the damage? Or is that only when a creature is blocking my creature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overthinking it. Two creatures fighting each other as result of a spell or ability means exactly what it says, and nothing more. Power and Toughness of a creature are always one certain value, namely the printed base value plus all applicable modifiers. Two creatures fighting each other is NOT combat, and combat-related abilities don't matter. The damage they deal to each other is NOT combat damage, but simply damage with the respective creature as the source.

Comment: Are you sure? I was fine with your answer (And I'm not saying you are wrong I'm asking for more clarification.) because I just noticed another card [mtg:Swift Kick] says the same thing, only does not include the part about dealing damage equal to its power

Comment: @128Gigabytes That is because the italicised part in brackets is called reminder text, and it's briefly reminding you how Fight works. Swift Kick doesn't include reminder text, but it's still how fight works. Reminder text is strictly not setting card rules itself, just reminding you of how the card rules work: consider Goblin Chieftain (has reminder text for haste) vs many other cards which do not include the reminder text; that doesn't change how Haste works.

Comment: @128Gigabytes - the part in parenthesis and italics is just an explanation of the rules language.  Sometimes they include it, especially if that language is relatively new.  If the language is the same, the rule is the same.  In this case, keyword fight means the same thing in both cases.